# HowTo read output of mongo print-command in php?

Tags: php, mongodb

Is it possible to read output of mongo commands by php driver? For example "print('hello')". I do it so:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager();
$cmd = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(
    [
        "eval" => "print('hello')"
    ]
);
$cursor = $manager->executeCommand("test", $cmd);
```

I get cursor, but foreach of it don`t give result. I tried dump cursor, but there is no "hello" word.

```
object(MongoDB\Driver\Cursor)#4 (9) {
  ["database"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["collection"]=>
  NULL
  ["query"]=>
  NULL
  ["command"]=>
  object(MongoDB\Driver\Command)#2 (1) {
    ["command"]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
      ["eval"]=>
      string(14) "print('hello')"
    }
  }
  ["readPreference"]=>
  NULL
  ["isDead"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["currentIndex"]=>
  int(0)
  ["currentDocument"]=>
  NULL
  ["server"]=>
  object(MongoDB\Driver\Server)#5 (10) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(9) "127.0.0.1"
    ["port"]=>
    int(27017)
    ["type"]=>
    int(1)
    ["is_primary"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["is_secondary"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["is_arbiter"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["is_hidden"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["is_passive"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["last_is_master"]=>
    array(8) {
      ["ismaster"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["maxBsonObjectSize"]=>
      int(16777216)
      ["maxMessageSizeBytes"]=>
      int(48000000)
      ["maxWriteBatchSize"]=>
      int(1000)
      ["localTime"]=>
      object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#6 (1) {
        ["milliseconds"]=>
        string(13) "1518334875740"
      }
      ["maxWireVersion"]=>
      int(4)
      ["minWireVersion"]=>
      int(0)
      ["ok"]=>
      float(1)
    }
    ["round_trip_time"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get output of concrete command?
Editor ask me add some more detils, but i don`t known what to add.

Comment: "_but there is no "hello" word._" Not quite true, there **is** the word `hello` in your output.

Comment: It`s only in "["eval"]=>      string(14) "print('hello')"", bun not in some result cell.